# WP user meta on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to pass WP user meta of the logged in user to a script. The script looks something like this like this:

```
Beacon("identify", {
  name: "Steve Aoki",
  email: "steve@aoki.com"
  "custom title": "Custom user meta"
});
```

How can I get the WP user meta of the logged in user? Are there any placeholder, what I can insert there?

It would be awesome, if you could help me or at least point me into the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: This should help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Comment: How and where are you using this script? Like, via functions.php or in footer.php?
You will need to get the user meta via php code and embed the javascript in php passing the retrieved user meta values to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve user meta in your PHP code using the `get_user_meta` function, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/).

> I need to pass WP user meta of the logged in user to a script.

The only way to do this in WordPress is to use the `wp_localize_script` function which allows you to access your server side data in your script. You can read more about it and see actual examples of it in use [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

I hope this helps